# DataTable - return search result

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a nice **DataTable** and I want to export it to a CSV, but only the rows shown by the searchbar search. as far as I'm concerned, I only need my first column (Id) to pass back to server. is there a method i could use to return the "search result" from the data table? thx!

Comment: If you're using TableTools to export the data you can add [oSelectorOpts](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21730/exporting-only-filtered-data-using-tabletools-button-collections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found that via the API i could just access the first column (and it returns the filtered data. this is the code:

```
relevant_ids = $('#myDataTable').DataTable().column(1).data()
```

cheers.